# Tooltips: JavaScript title manipula vs. title only

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, title

When will i want to use JavaScript to manipulate the title attribute instead f just title attribute, for tooltips?

Comment: What do you speak of? Please explain further.

Comment: I mean, between using just:
  
          <b id="text1" title="A bold text">Hello my friends!</a>


And using
     
 
         <b id="text1" title="A bold text">Hello my friends!</a>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById(text1).title="New tooltip"
      </script>

Comment: Why would anyone use a script for that? Just write `<b id="text1" title="New tooltip">Hello my friends!</a>`

Comment: When the value is not known beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use Javascript if you want the tooltip to change over the course of the form. For example, if you want to display a different tip after a button was clicked, then you would set the tooltip in the click handler for the button.

If the tooltip will never change, then just include it in the element.